# DNS lookup for instagram.com gives SERVFAIL - other domains work ok (Google Public DNS)

Tags: networking, mac, dns, domain-name, google-public-dns

Hi superuser community,

When querying instagram.com the host command (mac) responds with

```
Host instagram.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

However when querying other services such as `facebook.com` it responds with:

```
facebook.com has address 185.60.216.35
facebook.com has IPv6 address 2a03:2880:f12d:83:face:b00c::25de
facebook.com mail is handled by 10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com.
```

I am using Google public DNS.

Image with the output:

[image]

What is this caused by? How can I resolve this?

Comment: I can repro with `host instagram.com 8.8.8.8` though the domain resolves with my default resolver. Looks like maybe Google decided not to resolve instagram.com?

Comment: @tripleee Aha! Isn't this a very serious issue? I mean, Instagram is kinda big.. and Google DNS is widely used

Comment: I have no insight into what goals Google has with the public DNS, it could certainly be a mistake which they would like to be notified about.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I'm not suggesting malicious intent - more of a failure in the system. I have notified Google Public DNS user forum about the issue.

Comment: Apparently related to this: https://doublepulsar.com/hijack-of-amazons-internet-domain-service-used-to-reroute-web-traffic-for-two-hours-unnoticed-3a6f0dda6a6f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not only about instagram. A lot of our services are not resolvable by Google DNS.

I see a common pattern. All affected services are under Amazon AWS, maybe with Route 53 NSes.

UPD.
From the AWS status page.

> We are investigating reports of problems resolving some DNS records hosted on Route53 using the third party DNS resolvers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 . DNS resolution using other third-party DNS resolvers or DNS resolution from within EC2 instances using the default EC2 resolvers are not affected at this time.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. AWS status http://status.aws.amazon.com/ Confirms that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 1.1.1.1 or 9.9.9.9 for now. The same problem happened with me, and it was resolved by using another DNS.

```
➤ dig @1.1.1.1 instagram.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.7 <<>> @1.1.1.1 instagram.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13588
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1536
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;instagram.com.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
instagram.com.          46      IN      A       34.196.146.111
instagram.com.          46      IN      A       34.197.120.12
instagram.com.          46      IN      A       34.198.37.229
instagram.com.          46      IN      A       34.207.2.165
instagram.com.          46      IN      A       34.224.177.19
instagram.com.          46      IN      A       35.153.247.41
instagram.com.          46      IN      A       52.44.104.241
instagram.com.          46      IN      A       52.204.232.145

;; Query time: 260 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 24 15:50:49 AST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 170

                                                                                                                                                                    ✔
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[2018-04-24 15:50.49]  ~
 ➤ dig @8.8.8.8 instagram.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.7 <<>> @8.8.8.8 instagram.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 1926
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;instagram.com.                 IN      A

;; Query time: 168 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 24 15:51:02 AST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```